# How to sum numbers from list(s) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Learning python for two days :) and now I attempting to solve [Project Euler problem #2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2)  and I need help.

To be more specific, I need know know how to add numbers that were added to a empty list. I tried 'sum' but doesn't seems to work how the tutorial sites suggest. I'm using python 3. Here's my code so far:

```
a = 0
b = 1
n = a+b
while (n < 20):
   a, b = b, a + b
   n = a+b
   if n%2 == 0:
       mylist = []
       mylist.append(n)
       print(sum(mylist))
```

this outputs:

```
2
8
```

Now how do I add them? Thanks :)

Comment: So, you're asking Python to take the sum of a list with one element. What do you actually want to take the sum of?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget There's no input, it's generating a Fibonacci sequence, see the problem description: http://projecteuler.net/problem=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it right (the summing of the list), the main problem is with this statement:

```
mylist = []
```

move it before the `while` loop. Otherwise you are creating an new empy `mylist` *each* time through the loop.

Also, you probably want to print the sum of the list probably *after* you are done with your loop.

I.e.,

```
...
mylist = []
while (n < 20):
   a, b = b, a + b
   n = a+b
   if n%2 == 0:
       mylist.append(n)

print(sum(mylist))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new empty list just before you append a number to it, so you'll only ever have a one-element list.  Create the empty mylist once before you start.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that you have the list issue resolved, I would suggest an alternative to using a list.

Try the following solution that uses integer objects instead of lists:

```
f = 0
n = 1
r = 0

s = 0

while (n < 4000000):
    r = f + n
    f = n
    n = r
    if n % 2 == 0:
        s += n

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Ned & @Levon pointed out.

```
a = 0
b = 1
n = a+b
mylist = []
while (n < 20):
   a, b = b, a + b
   n = a+b
   if n%2 == 0:
       mylist.append(n)
print(sum(mylist))
```